# In angularjs make http service using promise

Tags: angularjs

When I hit the url for a particular page of the application, I want to check whether the page is allowed to load or not, using the api call. If it is, load that page, else redirect to different page of the application. For this I am using the http service with promise. Here the http service is not waiting for the http response.

```
    starter.service("verifywallet", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

this.getdata = function() {
    var url = baseAPIUrl + "IsEnableWallet/";
    var def = $q.defer();
    var IsEnableWallet = undefined;
    if (IsenableWallet) {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: url
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.status.success == true) {
                var IsenableWallet = response.data.status.Isenable;
                def.resolve(IsenableWallet);
            } else {
                def.resolve(false);
            }
        })
        IsenableWallet = def.promise;
    }
    return $q.when(IsenableWallet);
}

this.verify = function() {
    return this.getdata();
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this question is more related to your service not working instead the redirection that you mentioned, so you can try something like this:

```
starter.service("verifyWallet", ['$http', function($http) {

    var self = this;
    var baseAPIUrl = 'api/rest/'; //in your question there is no value for baseAPIUrl

    self.getData = function() {
        var IsEnableWallet = null; 
        var promise = $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: baseAPIUrl + "IsEnableWallet/";
        })

        return promise;
    }

}]);
```

After that, you can use the .then() when calling the function getData().

Besides, you shall not initialize variables as 'undefined', use null instead, and be carefull with the cammelCase (I.E. IsEnableWallet and IsenableWallet), javascript is key sensitive.